# I get an error when implementing tde in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tde

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ENCRYPTION
ALGORITHM = AES_256 BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TDECert

GO
```

when i execute this statement in SQL Server 2008 I get the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'KEY'.
>  Msg 319, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 2
>  Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression or an
>   xmlnamespaces clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

What to do?
I just want to encrypt my db.

Comment: Please make an effort to use real words in your question

Comment: And reading the documentation would help. What you want us to do? Copy/Paste?

Comment: Next time, please format your question.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I see between your example and the MSDN example is the capitalization of the word `WITH`

Answer (score 1):

what you miss is  **Encryption by** so the corrected script will be  below:

```
USE MyDatabase 
GO 
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY 
WITH ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM = AES_256 
 ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TDECert  
GO
```